# Android RecyclerView to avoid scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image]

I have a RecyclerView which is at the bottom.It shows one item out of multiple items and is scrolling independently in a very small space and due to that i can only see 1 item at on time.
I want to avoid that scrolling and the whole inner fragment should be scrolled.
You can see the attached image.

My inner Fragment layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".fragments.gamedetail.StatisticsFragment">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewTeamLogo"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:text="MAN"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewTeamLogo"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewTeamLogoAway"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:text="WHU"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageViewTeamLogoAway"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Game Stats"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewBPHome"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                android:text="100"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewBP"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Ball Possession"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textViewBPAway"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textViewBPHome"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewBPAway"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|fill_horizontal|center"
                android:text="100"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#efefef" />

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewSonTHome"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                android:text="100"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewSonT"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Shots on target"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textViewSOTAway"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textViewSonTHome"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewSOTAway"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|fill_horizontal|center"
                android:text="100"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#efefef" />

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewSoFFTHome"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                android:text="100"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewSOFFT"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Shots off target"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textViewSOFFTAway"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textViewSoFFTHome"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewSOFFTAway"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|fill_horizontal|center"
                android:text="100"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#efefef" />

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewCHome"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                android:text="100"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewC"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Corners"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textViewCAway"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textViewCHome"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewCAway"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|fill_horizontal|center"
                android:text="100"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#efefef" />

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewFHome"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                android:text="100"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewF"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Fouls"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textViewFAway"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textViewFHome"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewFAway"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|fill_horizontal|center"
                android:text="100"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#efefef" />

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewOHome"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                android:text="100"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewO"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Offsides"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textViewOAway"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textViewOHome"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewOAway"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|fill_horizontal|center"
                android:text="100"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#efefef" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Form Guide"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewTeamLogoFormguide"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewhomeShortname"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:text="MAN"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewTeamLogoFormguide"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewTeamLogoAwayFormGuid"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewAwayshortname"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="WHU"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageViewTeamLogoAwayFormGuid"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewFormGuide"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried by adding setNestedScrollingEnabled(false) but its not working

```
recyclerViewFormGuide = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewFormGuide);
recyclerViewFormGuide.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
recyclerViewFormGuide.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
FormGuideAdapter formGuideAdapter=new FormGuideAdapter(getActivity(),formGuideRows);
recyclerViewFormGuide.setAdapter(formGuideAdapter);
```

Comment: the recycler which is independently scrolling you want to show all of the content of it ? i.e. you don't need scrolling behavior ?

Comment: add the content of yout *inner fragment* as a header of the RecyclerView. This way it will scroll all together

Comment: @UmarHussain yes i don't want the scrolling behavior of the recyclerView

Comment: If you don't want scrolling behavior of the recycler view, then why using a recyclerview?
Simply use the item view directly in the layout.

Comment: @Nouman Have you tried giving recyclerView height to MatchParent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `ScrollView` in your layout. What it will do is `Override` the scrolling behavior of `recyclerView` And also I believe you will be able to scroll your whole layout instead of only `recylerView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewTeamLogo"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:text="MAN"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewTeamLogo"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewTeamLogoAway"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:text="WHU"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageViewTeamLogoAway"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView11"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Game Stats"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewBPHome"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                    android:text="100"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewBP"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Ball Possession"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textViewBPAway"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textViewBPHome"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewBPAway"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|fill_horizontal|center"
                    android:text="100"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#efefef" />

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewSonTHome"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                    android:text="100"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewSonT"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Shots on target"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textViewSOTAway"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textViewSonTHome"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewSOTAway"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|fill_horizontal|center"
                    android:text="100"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#efefef" />

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewSoFFTHome"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                    android:text="100"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewSOFFT"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Shots off target"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textViewSOFFTAway"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textViewSoFFTHome"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewSOFFTAway"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|fill_horizontal|center"
                    android:text="100"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#efefef" />

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewCHome"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                    android:text="100"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewC"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Corners"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textViewCAway"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textViewCHome"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewCAway"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|fill_horizontal|center"
                    android:text="100"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#efefef" />

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewFHome"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                    android:text="100"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewF"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Fouls"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textViewFAway"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textViewFHome"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewFAway"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|fill_horizontal|center"
                    android:text="100"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#efefef" />

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewOHome"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                    android:text="100"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewO"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Offsides"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textViewOAway"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textViewOHome"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewOAway"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|fill_horizontal|center"
                    android:text="100"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#efefef" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Form Guide"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewTeamLogoFormguide"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewhomeShortname"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                    android:text="MAN"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewTeamLogoFormguide"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewTeamLogoAwayFormGuid"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewAwayshortname"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="WHU"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageViewTeamLogoAwayFormGuid"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewFormGuide"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="250dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Happy coding :)